# Переход в DetailView из ScrollView через NavigationView при заработке приложений под MacOS(SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Как правильно сделать переход в DetailView через ScrollView, в разработке приложений под MacOS? Пробовал для iPhone все корректно отрабатывает.

**Код проекта для MacOS**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
          NavigationLink(destination: CityDetailView()) {
            ZStack {
              Color.red
              Text("123123123")
            }
          }
          NavigationLink(destination: CityDetailView()) {
            ZStack {
              Color.red
              Text("123123123")
            }
          }
          NavigationLink(destination: CityDetailView()) {
            ZStack {
              Color.red
              Text("123123123")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView().frame(minWidth: 1024, minHeight: 768)
  }
}
```

Таким образом отображется 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фон в DetailView залил зеленым фоном. На скрине видно как отображается его кусок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Реализация CityDetailView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CityDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
      Color.green
    }
}

struct CityDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CityDetailView()
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите реализацию `CityDetailView`

Comment: Добавил код CityDetailView в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускаю ваш код на чистом проекте код в XCode 11.4.1 и получаю такую картину, поэтому попробуйте поступить так же и потом уже разбирайтесь что пошло не так с макетом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PavelAnpleenko скачайте по ссылке https://yadi.sk/d/maOoQJlgIRPoYQ

Comment: Спасибо буду изучать